# Iterate through all images

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to iterate through all the .png images that are resources in my iPhone game? Maybe having a filter to only find for me images that begin with a certain prefix...

I know it sounds weird. It is like considering I don't even know what images I got in my project. Well, this is more for experimentation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You use the appropriate `NSBundle` for this, if this is the main bundle, this would look like this:

```
NSArray *allPNGs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
```

You can then iterate through the array and check the prefixes of the returned files.